# Evolution of an objects properties using TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have the situation in which I have a domain entity which can be in a "just born" state and then more mature state, once more data is fetched from a 3rd party.

A simple example would be:

```
interface Props {
  name: string;
  idFrom3pAPI?: string;
}
```

When a request arrives to my system I would like to create the domain object, but some data will be missing, I will then pass this object to a service/repo which will obtain the missing keys and return the complete object.

The issue with the above type is that when I try to pass this object to the ORM it will not type check as `idFrom3pAPI` cannot be undefined.

So essentially I am looking for a conditional or discriminated union type, where I could set a flag on the objects state, and the type checker would be happy that it now has the correct data.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: TypeScript doesn't do type mutations on non-union types automatically, but you can use an assertion function to get this effect, so instead of `o.k=v` you do `setProp(o, "k", v)` and then `o` will be narrowed.  Like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WG5VVN).  If that meets your needs I can maybe write up an answer; if not, what am I missing? (It helps if you provide a [mre] of the issue so that I have something to code against, instead of just a text description of the issue)

Comment: I think this would be a good answer :)

Answer (score 1):

I may not be reading your question correctly, however I agree with your initial attempt where `idFrom3pAPI` is optional if it in fact may or may not exist. However, if your ORM cannot accept `idFrom3pAPI` being an optional, then this solution should work.

First, remove the optional from `idFrom3API`

```
interface Props {
  name: string;
  idFrom3pAPI: string;
}
```

Then you can use the `Partial` [utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#partialtype) when you pass it to the "service/repo" and that "service/repo" would return the full type. The "service/repo" should accept Partial and return `Props`. The variable that receives the initial request would be `Partial<Props>` and a new variable of type `Props` would receive the result from your "service/repo"

Then your ORM can accept `Props` as defined above without the optional.

Another option would be to create a different type and later [narrow](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html) it to the type the ORM wants.